# SimpleForm Collection For Sizes In Stock of Associated Item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have BaseProducts and Products.

I display BaseProducts, and a user can select certain options there (size, etc).  My goal is to then FIND the product_id with those associations.

Right now, I have a shirt item.  It has Sizes. I've created a Size table that has many different sizes. XXS -> XXXL and eventually I may want to add 0-12 (or whatever I'm a dude).

I want the collection field in my form to only show the sizes that said shirt has available.

```
<%= f.input :size, :label => false, collection: base_product.products.collect {|product| product.size},
:label_method => :size_letter,
:value_method => :id,
:include_blank => false
 %>
```

This is good, but i twill return all sizes, even the ones that have 0 stock.  I tried

```
<%= f.input :size, :label => false, collection: base_product.products.collect {|product| product.size if product.stock_qty > 0},
:label_method => :size_letter,
:value_method => :id,
:include_blank => false
 %>
```

but that returns an error

```
undefined method `size_letter' for nil:NilClass
```

Not sure why I am getting nilclass.  **How can I limit the options of sizes to the ones the product has, and are in stock?**
Update - > I've added models for Size and Product
    class Size < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :product
      validates_uniqueness_of :size_letter
    end

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :base_product
  has_many :line_items
  belongs_to :size
  belongs_to :color
  validates_uniqueness_of :base_product_id, :scope => [:size_id]

  def is_base_product?
    return true if self.class.name == "BaseProduct" 
  end
  def is_product?
    return true if self.class.name == "Product" 
  end
  def in_stock
    self.stock_qty > 0
  end
end
```

Also,

Here is some live shell code...

```
>> base_product.products.collect {|product| product.size}
=> [#<Size id: 2, created_at: "2014-11-08 18:26:57", updated_at: "2014-11-08 18:26:57",  
size_letter: "XXS">, #<Size id: 3, created_at: "2014-11-08 18:26:57", updated_at: "2014-11-08
18:26:57", size_letter: "XS">, #<Size id: 4, created_at: "2014-11-08 18:26:57",
updated_at: "2014-11-08 18:26:57", size_letter: "S">, #<Size id: 5, created_at: 
"2014-11-08 18:26:57", updated_at: "2014-11-08 18:26:57", size_letter: "M">, #<Size id: 7,  
created_at: "2014-11-08 18:26:57", updated_at: "2014-11-08 18:26:57", size_letter: "XL">,
#<Size id: 8, created_at: "2014-11-08 18:26:57", updated_at: "2014-11-08 18:26:57", size_letter:
"XXL">]
```

So I am returning an array of objects, which is what I want... right?

When I try to eliminate products with stock_qty of 0:

```
base_product.products.collect {|product| product.size if product.stock_qty > 0}
=> [#<Size id: 2, created_at: "2014-11-08 18:26:57", updated_at: "2014
-11-08 18:26:57", size_letter: "XXS">, #<Size id: 3, created_at: "2014
-11-08 18:26:57", updated_at: "2014-11-08 18:26:57", size_letter: "XS"
>, #<Size id: 4, created_at: "2014-11-08 18:26:57", updated_at: "2014-
11-08 18:26:57", size_letter: "S">, #<Size id: 5, created_at: "2014-11
-08 18:26:57", updated_at: "2014-11-08 18:26:57", size_letter: "M">, #
<Size id: 7, created_at: "2014-11-08 18:26:57", updated_at: "2014-11-
08 18:26:57", size_letter: "XL">, nil]
```

This works in shell, notice XXL (which had qty 0) is missing from the second response.  It does not however, work within the view it's rendered in.

Comment: can you post your model?

Comment: Your `collect` returns array containing either `integer` or `nil`, if I'm reading this correctly.  You want to be returning `product` not `product.size`.  Then you might also want to call `compact` on the `collect`, so that all products that are unavailable are removed. This should prevent the error from happening.

Comment: @vee I think I do want to call product.size.  I want an array of all the sizes that are available for each product.

Comment: @Peege151, I apologize, I assumed the size_letter was in `product`.

Comment: I may want to change that, yeah... size_letter is the field in Size that corresponds with the id so id:1, size_letter "S" etc.